# How to reset Jquery effect in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to click on the canvas, drop it on the map, then click on it again to move it within the map. I tried to do that with anonymous function but it does not work. Here is the link for the demo and the code I have so far

https://pokemon-map-electro2k.c9users.io/index.html

```
// Anonymous function
var movecanvas = function () {
    return onmousemove();
};

var onmousemove = function ($canvas) {

    // Make canvas follow cursor in the map area
    $(".map").mousemove(function (e) {

        $(".map ul li." + $canvas).offset({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    }).click(function () {
        // Disable mousemove when canvas is clicked within a map. Drop the canvas on the map
        $(".map").unbind("mousemove");

        // When canvas is click on again within the map area, make canvas follow cursor
        $(".map ul li").click(function () {
            movecanvas($canvas);  // Repeat $(".map").mousemove over here. But how??
        });
    });





    // De-select canvas if click on .palette div and reset Jquery effect
    $(".palette ul li." + $canvas).click(function () {
        $(".map ul li." + $canvas).fadeOut("slow", function () {$(".map ul li." + $canvas).remove()});
        $($container).find("." + $canvas).removeClass("selected");
        $("#document").replaceWith(paletteClone.clone(true));       // reset the DOM then manipulate it again
    });

    var paletteClone = $(document).clone(true);     // bound handler for .palette div

};
```

Comment: Take a read through this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-domjquery/

Comment: Your link does not seem to work, can you provide a working fiddle/demo with the problem?

Comment: It should works now. I enable it